# How to send Method's name for elements

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making method to make button easily. but I don't know how to send method's name.. which is a button have to be called when user press this button. Is there any way to send this name?

I want to know "???????????????????"part on my source below..

this source is part of "Support.m" which I'm making.
Thanks..

```
+ (id)CreateButton:(id)layer (NSString*)filename secondfilename:(NSString*)filename2 sameimage:(BOOL)sameimage position:(CGPoint)position
{  
    CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:filename]];
    CCSprite *sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:filename2]];

    CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWith
    CCMenuItem *MenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalSprite:sprite1 selectedSprite:sprite2 target:layer selector:@selector(???????????????????????????????)];
    MenuItem.position = position;
    CCMenu *Menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:MenuItem, nil];
    Menu.position = CGPointZero;
    return Menu;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I want to use this method in any other source file. so I need to send my method's name!

Comment: What do you mean send the name? Normally you would just type the methods name there, like `@selector(methodNameWithParameter:)`

Comment: If that method is placed on other source? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the name of the method which you want to be called when that menu item is selected:

```
 CCMenuItem *MenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalSprite:sprite1 
                                               selectedSprite:sprite2 
                                                       target:layer 
                                                     selector:@selector(methodToRunWhenMenuItemIsSelected:)];
```

Whatever object the target is, in this case `layer` then needs to have a method of that name implemented:

```
 - (void) methodToRunWhenMenuItemIsSelected: (CCMenuItem *)item {
     // Do something interesting
 }
```

Comment: but I want to place "mehtodToRunWhenMenuItemIsSelected:" to other source... that's what I want..

Comment: What do you mean by "place" and "source"? These are not terms that apply in this context.

Comment: The Method which I want to call isn't placed on same source file.. on other class.. do you understand?

Comment: It doesn't matter what file it's in. You just give the menu item the selector you want it to call and the target you want it to use, and then later the menu item does `[target performSelector:theSelector withObject:self];`, and your method is called.

Comment: sorry... I can't understand why you say "it doesn't matter". You know what I mean?... thanks anyway..^^